# cakephp 1.3: find conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

```
   Array
  (
     [0] => Array
       (
        [DebateComment] => Array
            (
                [id] => 126
                [user_id] => 17
                [debate_id] => 32
                [debate_comment_title] => hiiiiiii
                [debate_comments] => gfdfg dfg .

                [debate_type] => against
                [total_postive_counts] => 1
                [total_negative_counts] => 0
                [accept_challenges] => Enable
                [status] => Active
                [modified] => 2011-08-19 11:12:59
                [created] => 2011-08-18 17:50:53
            )

        [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 17
                [group_id] => 3
                [fb_user_id] => 0
                [username] => xyz
                [email] => xyz@xyz.com
                [password] => 077dadf3cc9c5fcb95dfacc3d8ff5049123b2d89
                [status] => 1
                [verify_code] => 
                [signup_ip] => 
                [is_verified] => 1
                [user_comment_warn_status] => 0
                [user_ip_address] => 
                [referred_by_user_id] => 0
                [twitter_user_id] => 0
                [twitter_access_key] => 
                [twitter_access_token] => 
                [modified] => 2011-05-05 10:43:15
                [Userdetail] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14
                        [user_id] => 17
                        [firstname] => xyz
                        [lastname] => 
                        [about_me] => 
                        [tagline] => 

                        [visible_status] => Online

                        [show_welcome_message] => Yes
                        [created] => 2011-05-05 10:43:15
                        [modified] => 2011-05-05 10:43:15


                    )

                )
    )
```

Above array describe relation with eachother.

I write this query but dosent get output.

```
$arr = $this->DebateComment->find('all',array(
           'conditions'=>array('User.Userdetail.visible_status'=>'Online'), 'recursive'=>3));
```

My Question :

I want to find all DebateComment .but conditions is that visibale_status => online in Userdetails.

Comment: Is it CakePHP version 1.2 or 1.3?

Comment: @OZ_ : i write join query but yet doesnt get proper output.if you have any idea about of it then write perfect Query in cakephp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$users = $this->DebateComment->User->Userdetail->find('list',array(
    'fields'=>array('user_id'),
    'conditions'=>array('Userdetail.visible_status'=>'Online')
));
$arr = $this->DebateComment->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array('DebateComment.user_id'=>$users)
));
```

You can use either containable or recursive to get the related data in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it is the comment but i dont see any option to comment on your question in my interface.I assume this is a result of a JOIN have you implemented BELONGSTO association here or any one else?Have you tried mentioning the visibale_status ONLINE in the JOIN condition?Did it worked then?Also there is another way to get recursive data.try

```
$this->DebateComment-recursive = 3
```

I am not sure of level of recursion here.Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = $this->DebateComment->find('all',array('joins' => array(array('table' => 'userdetails','alias' => 'Userdetail','type' => 'INNER','foreignKey' => false,'conditions' => array('DebateComment.user_id = Userdetail.user_id','Userdetail.visible_status'=>'Online'))),
 'recursive'=> 2));
```